# How to autoupdate a forum thread when new posts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, greasemonkey

Greasemonkey plugin. (js/ajax, jquery optional).

- Want to autoupdate forum pages when they get changed (new posts, for instance). Ideally with no page refresh.
- Additionally, if I can make it load multi-page threads in one page (when applicable, perfect).
- Don't want to lose content in response boxes if there's any text in them.
- Site: Paizo.com.

How would you guys go about doing this?

Comment: I suppose it wasnt the best question:

I'm trying to determine how to figure out if the page has been updated.

No code yet, I've been looking for information via google to explain how to check for page updates and my google fu has been failing me.

So far I have the very basics, javascript code to refresh a page, and information on jquery's ajax() function and get function.

I'm new to ajax.

Comment: Show your current serious attempt to construct such a script, and ask specific questions regarding it. Examples: **Good question**: "I have ___, I want ___, but I'm stuck at __ with error message ___. I have already tried __, but unfortunately ___". **Bad question**: "I want ___ and __. How?". **EDIT**: If you're referring to content from other pages, at least add an URL to your question.

Comment: Alright.

Its also my first question up here.

I'll come back once I've got something more concrete.

Comment: I dont know why the post/question got duplicated. Maybe I hit refresh or something. Still working on it.

Answer (score 0):

loop `GM_xmlhttpRequest` to get the forum page in a 15 minutes interval.
save the response, and compare with the last one.
keep only the content that was added, and display it any way you see fit (i would use a `div`).

in this example [here](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/124687) you can see how to use `GM_xmlhttpRequest`, create a `DIV` on the fly, store the desired content into it, and use its data as a parameter to request another page with `GM_xmlhttpRequest` again, repeating the cycle.

if you want me to explain the script, let me know.